# helenus bigint insertion gives error

Tags: node.js, cassandra, helenus

I'm currently using helenus library for inserting a column family.

```
CREATE TABLE page_request (
  c_date text,
  c_id timeuuid,
  s bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_date, c_id)
);
```

I'm parsing the integer by `parseInt();`.

I'm using prepared statement of helenus. However, when my big integer `s` is bigint, `parseInt()` function converts this integer to float. Is there any specific case for inserting bigint to helenus ?

NOTE: `Number()` function also doesn't work

Comment: I've experienced similar issues with the datatypes in Helenus, and fixed them by modifying the serializers in the marshal folder, I just can't remember what I modified as it's been some time since I did the changes, but I do remember I rewrote several of the serializers as many of them are faulty when dealing with numbers.

Comment: @adeneo I've moved to https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client. The driver gives bigint support and the project seems to be more active.